# Image file to PDF Conversion in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app,

I have to convert Image File to PDF.

Is there any way, how to do it and which Libraries are available freely?

Thanks!!

Comment: SO rules do not allow this kind of questions. 3rd party library recommendations should be asked here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @iPDFdev I didn't know about it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, whoever wants it. Its working and tested.

I have added ComponentOne Library in Windows Phone 8.1 Project.

```
using C1.Phone.Pdf;
using C1.Phone.PdfViewer;

C1PdfDocument pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated);
pdf.Landscape = true;

var rc = new System.Windows.Rect(20,30,300,200);
pdf.DrawImage(wbitmp, rc);

var fillingName = "Test.pdf";
var gettingFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var loadingFinalStream = gettingFile.CreateFile(fillingName))
{
   pdf.Save(loadingFinalStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a client site js library called [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) which is worth giving a try.

Comment: fill in the form below the download button to get the download. Beyond that it's free (MIT licence).